# Twilio Laravel 4 validate phone number with country code

Tags: php, laravel-4, twilio

How to validate phone number with country code using laravel 4

Below is my code

```
use Aloha\Twilio\Twilio;

    $phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber($this->phoneNo, $this->countryCode);

        // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
        $sid = "11111";
        $token = "rtrg";
        $client = new Lookups_Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

        $number = $client->phone_numbers->get($this->phoneNo, array("CountryCode" => $this->countryCode, "Type" => "carrier"));
```

I'm getting following error:

> Class 'Managers\Lookups_Services_Twilio' not found

Please advise.

Comment: Try `$client = new \Lookups_Services_Twilio(...);`  It looks like its trying to load it from the current namespace you are in.